# Why does a SASS exception become `nil` by calling `backtrace` on it?

Tags: ruby, exception, sass

The code below defines a hook `Kernel#at_exit` to capture an exception and do things at exit, and then raises a `Sass::SyntaxError` by passing an invalid SASS string.

```
require "sass"

module Kernel
  at_exit do
    puts "--Before backtrace"
    p $!
    $!.backtrace
    puts "--After backtrace"
    p $!
  end
end

Sass::Engine.new("Invalid {sass").render
```

The output it gives is as below:

```
...
--Before backtrace
#<Sass::SyntaxError: ...>
--After backtrace
nil
...
```

It indicates that `$!` was a `Sass::SyntaxError`, but it became `nil` right after `backtrace` has been called on it. Why did `$!` change just by calling `backtrace` on it?

This effect does not seem to happen when `Sass::SyntaxError` is raised manually as follows:

```
raise Sass::SyntaxError.new("foo")
```

or when a different type of error is raised (may be wrong).

**Edit**

I am not sure, but probably sass manipulates the backtrace using `set_backtrace` when a sass error is raised. This is to provide information about where the sass syntax error was caused in a sass file. And the different behaviour between manually raising an error and programatically raising an error is reminiscent of a bug in Ruby 2.1 that half-way implemented `backtrace_locations`, but returned `nil` in some cases. I have a broad guess that these factors are interfering, but am not sure.

Comment: Very nice question, I am digging into it but have no clue whatsoever. BTW: You don need to open Kernel module to call `at_exit`

Comment: for me it is not `nil`... `module Kernel
  at_exit do
    puts "--Before backtrace"
    p $!
    $!.backtrace
    puts "--After backtrace"
    p $!
  end
end

raise 'error'
# ~> -:11:in '<main>': error (RuntimeError)
# >> --Before backtrace
# >> #<RuntimeError: error>
# >> --After backtrace
# >> #<RuntimeError: error>`

Comment: @ArupRakshit - You got runtime error instead of Sass::SyntaxError error - something else is throwing there.

Comment: @BroiSatse That's true... I was checking if the issue is universal or with the specific case.

Comment: @sawa - regarding your update: I have just created my own exception class which very closely imitated `Sass::SyntaxError` backtrace method, but it worked as expected. Still, I can't imagine how this would clear the $! variable.

Comment: @BroiSatse Looking forward for you to come up with something. I can't imagine too, given that `$!` cannot be assigned manually. I don't even know if this is a Ruby bug or Sass bug, or both.

Comment: Ok another point to look at: `at_exit { p $@; p $@ }` is also returning different values (an array and nil).

Comment: It seems you were right - it is caused by this fiddling and my exception was not close enough to catch it. I'll post an answer in a minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it is happening is because this method overrides backtrace method:

```
def backtrace
  return nil if super.nil?
  return super if sass_backtrace.all? {|h| h.empty?}
  sass_backtrace.map do |h|
    "#{h[:filename] || "(sass)"}:#{h[:line]}" +
      (h[:mixin] ? ":in `#{h[:mixin]}'" : "")
  end + super
end
```

Where `sass_backtrace` is an array of hashes populated in initializer. Line which causes `$!` to be `nil` is:

```
return super if sass_backtrace.all? {|h| h.empty?}
```

This happens only when `all?` returns `nil`. I did some fiddling with it, and I found out that the problem always occurs, when we call any iterator which doesn't finish the whole iteration (`all?` terminates iteration when encounter the first not satisfying element). The problem might be simply reproduced with:

```
at_exit do
  p $!         #=> #<RuntimeError: hello>
  [<any_non_empty_array>].all? {false}

  # Those would break $! as well
  # [<ANA>].any? {true}
  # [1,2,3].find {|n| n.even?}

  # Those will not break $!
  # [<ANA>].any? {false}
  # [<ANA>].all? {true}
  # [1,2,3].find {|n| n > 4}
  p $!         #=> nil
end

raise 'hello'
```

The only reason I can think of why it would work like that is that ruby loops are controlled internally with exceptions. When iteration is to be stopped, it is done with special type of exception being raised and rescued outside the loop.

My guess is that Ruby creators didn't want this control exception to be visible in `$!` variable, since this would suggest that something went wrong, and decided to set it back to `nil`.

Comment: Wonderful and perfect answer. I now understand what was going on. Thanks for spending your time.